# Refresh page when flash crashes (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox

I'm having an issue where my flash project crashes during 'Crazy kid Testing' - Where we click the same button several times and then do the same on another button. If the same button is clicked repeatedly, 10-12 times,  Flash Player (SWF) crashes.

Is there any method to automatically reload the page when flash crashes WITHOUT user input? This will be used on a Kiosk in Firefox (latest).

Comment: no when flash crashes that's the end of the app so nothing else can happen and the html or javascript can't see it.

Comment: You should debug your Flash app for memory leaks first, because Flash crashing is not a sign of good application. And if Flash would still crash after all memory leaks eliminated, you should reduce the memory footprint of your app. Anything beyond, and only a watchdog could save you.

Comment: @BotMaster A probable scenario of Flash crash detection: Use `ExternalInterface` to call a timer reset function in Javascript, and the timer is set so that if three calls are expected but none fired, and if that timer reset function has been called (which indicates to JS side that `ExternalInterface` is available in Flash side), refresh the page.

Comment: yep I guess that would work

Comment: I did some testing using Adobe Scout, noticed multiple netstreams open even after several minutes of inactivity. 33 streams decoding at it's peak. I followed a post here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083390/as3-netstream-doesnt-seem-to-close with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Vesper had the right idea when it comes to both using `ExternalInterface` and probing for memory leaks and resolving those leaks.

> You should debug your Flash app for memory leaks first, because Flash
>   crashing is not a sign of good application. And if Flash would still
>   crash after all memory leaks eliminated, you should reduce the memory
>   footprint of your app. Anything beyond, and only a watchdog could save
>   you. –  Vesper Jun 6 at 18:20